# Size of master detailed view changes when a accessed the second time (IOS 6)

Tags: templates, ios6

I am using the master detail template as the basis for a universal application.
When using the detailed view in portrait mode, the first time you access the view, the height is 1004
The second time I access the same view, it comes back with a height of 960.

I checked this is the empty template and this happens there as well.

I am using the view bounds properties to determine the height.

What is causing this and can this be fixed?